# Calling Google Book API experience!! Can i use Google Books API to extract ingredient lists from recipe books?

Tags: google-api, google-books

I'm from a non-tech background so would really like some help to validate if something is possible, before i hire a freelancer to do the data entry work.

I need to extract certain data of every recipe in a specific list of recipe books, including: 
    - the recipe title, 
    - no. of people the recipe serves, 
    - amount that the recipe makes, 
    - ingredient name, and,
    - ingredient quantity.

Public access to google books won't work as half the pages are restricted from view. Therefore i thought google books API would allow this.

Does anyone have experience with Google Books API to confirm if this is possible?

Victoria

Answer (score 0):

While the Google Books api does let you search for books

GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/2gLHReHXK80C

```
{
 "kind": "books#volume",
 "id": "2gLHReHXK80C",
 "etag": "xAHG2BOsg/Y",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/2gLHReHXK80C",
 "volumeInfo": {
  "title": "Cooking, Cuisine and Class",
  "subtitle": "A Study in Comparative Sociology",
  "authors": [
   "Jack Goody"
  ],
  "publisher": "Cambridge University Press",
  "publishedDate": "1982-06-24",
  "description": "The preparation, serving and eating of food are common features of all human societies, and have been the focus of study for numerous anthropologists - from Sir James Frazer onwards - from a variety of theoretical and empirical perspectives. It is in the context of this previous anthropological work that Jack Goody sets his own observations on cooking in West Africa. He criticises those approaches which overlook the comparative historical dimension of culinary, and other, cultural differences that emerge in class societies, both of which elements he particularly emphasises in this book. The central question that Professor Goody addresses here is why a differentiated 'haute cuisine' has not emerged in Africa, as it has in other parts of the world. His account of cooking in West Africa is followed by a survey of the culinary practices of the major Eurasian societies throughout history - ranging from Ancient Egypt, Imperial Rome and medieval China to early modern Europe - in which he relates the differences in food preparation and consumption emerging in these societies to differences in their socio-economic structures, specifically in modes of production and communication. He concludes with an examination of the world-wide rise of 'industrial food' and its impact on Third World societies, showing that the ability of the latter to resist cultural domination in food, as in other things, is related to the nature of their pre-existing socio-economic structures. The arguments presented here will interest all social scientists and historians concerned with cultural history and social theory.",
.....
}
```

It does not give you access to actually search the contents of the book.   The google books api is a public api.  Even if you look at book shelf you are only going to get information back on the books the user owns.  Your not going to be able to read or scan the consent of the book.   All you will get is the metadata information on the book itself.